# ClassNotFoundException / org.apache.pivot.wtk.BrowserApplicationContext$HostApplet

Tags: java, class

Is there any version of JAVA, or an alternative to JAVA, which is compatible with dial-up.   I keep getting the following exception even when using Google Chrome or FireFox.

> ClassNotFoundException / org.apache.pivot.wtk.BrowserApplicationContext$HostApplet

I have the latest JAVA Version.  Are there any older versions still available?  JAVA.com does not seem to have it's own customer support centre

Everything else out there is either pay-by-the-minute or "buy our fix-it program"

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take a minute to consider your post. In order to help people need to see a minimal example of your code that demonstrates this error. There is also the tagging system, this website hosts questions on many languages so please ensure you always tag your question with the correct language.

Comment: You seem very confused about something. Please re-read your question and try rephrasing it so people can understand your problem. Specifically, what are you trying to do and show us a little code

Answer (score 0):

Not all existing Java libraries are included in the JDK. You seem to have a piece of code which refers to a library called [Apache Pivot](http://pivot.apache.org/). You need to make sure that you have the jar file(s) for this library and that they are in your CLASSPATH when you execute your program. I think you need to find a good book or tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of including your library to the CLASSPATH environment variable you can also copy the external jar-files to your jdk and jre.
On my system thats for example:
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\jre\lib\ext\
and
C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\ext\

I have better experiences with that, than setting the CLASSPATH.